# How to get phones from users collection

Tags: meteor

I need to get all phone numbers to textarea  from users collection.How can  I do?

> SMSnumaralar=textarea

```
Template.uyelereSMSgonder.events({
    'click #numaralariKopyala': function (e, template) {
     var getdata=Meteor.users.find({});
     template.$('#SMSnumaralar').val(getdata.profile.phone);

        }
      });
```

Comment: Couple questions, edit your question for more clarity: you want to get *all* users' phone numbers, and put them *all* in the same `#SMSnumaralar` textarea? Following what pattern? One phone number per line?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You can extract an array of just the phone numbers easily using `map`, then `join` it with a given a separating character (a newline in my example), and finally put your newly created string of phone numbers in the textarea:

```
Template.uyelereSMSgonder.events({
    'click #numaralariKopyala': function (e, template) {
     var phoneNumbers=Meteor.users.find({}).map(function (user) {
       return user.profile.phone;
     }).join('\n');
     template.$('#SMSnumaralar').val(phoneNumbers);
    }
 });
```